# sed replace text in a XML file

Tags: sed

I have huge XML file with data like this:

```
<amount quantity="1">12.00</amount>
```

How can i replace the 12.00 with something else using sed?

Comment: While `sed` is a very flexible tool for many textfile manipulations, esp. in combination with other pipe-enable shell commands, this really seems a better task for a quick-and-dirty XSLT pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really enough information in your question but to replace all values of `12.00` with say `24.00` you could do:

```
$ sed 's/>12\.00</>24.00</g' file.xml
```

If you are happy with the results you can store them back using the `-i` option:

```
$ sed -i 's/>12\.00</>24.00</g' file.xml
```

A more rubust match would be:

```
$ sed -r 's_(<amount quantity="[0-9]+">)12.00(</amount>)_\124.00\2_g' file.xml
```

But you should really parse the XML properly and not force regexp to do something it wasn't designed for.

Comment: I was going to suggest using the closing tag `</amount>` to define the search pattern, following of course the `12.00`.  This would avoid problems with 12.00 appearing in other contexts.

Comment: @hardmath that may be better but since the OP provided very little info it's impossible to say.

Answer (score 0):

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
xml="<amount quantity="1">12.00</amount>"
newxml=`echo $xml | sed -n "s/\(<amount[^>]*>\)\([^<]*\)\(<\/amount>\)/\113.37\3/gp"`
echo "$newxml"
```

result:

```
$ ./script.sh 
<amount quantity=1>13.37</amount>
```